# где isNaN подскажите пожалуйста я что-то не понял?

Tags: javascript

```js
alert(isNaN(1s2ssa));
```

есть функция isNaN которая проверяет число. Если это NAN возвращает true, иначе false. Я в alert записал не число, значит будет true, почему тогда мне на экран ничего не выводится ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Что Вы думаете по поводу сообщения об ошибке, которое появляется, когда Вы нажимаете на кнопку "Выполнить код"?*

В Вашей строчке кода наслоилось несколько ошибок.

Что такое для парсера `1s2ssa`? "Возможно, это переменная" - думает парсер. Но идентификаторы переменных не могут начинаться с цифры - выкидываем ошибку (см. ошибку в вопросе) и прекращаем парсить код. Произошла *ошибка компиляции*.

```js
console.log("test 0");
alert(isNaN(1s2ssa));
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `"test 0"` в консоль не выводится.

Хорошо, поставим в начало идентификатора букву:

```js
console.log("test 1");
alert(isNaN(a1s2ssa));
```

Код распарсен и начинает выполняться (см. вывод в консоли - `"test 1"`). Но теперь, выполнятель натыкается на использование переменной, которая нигде не объявлена, и мы получаем другую ошибку. Произошла *ошибка выполнения*.

Хорошо, объявим переменную.

```js
var a1s2ssa;
console.log("test 2");
alert(isNaN(a1s2ssa));
```

Наконец-то!

Возможно, Вы имели ввиду вызвать `isNaN` с параметром-строкой, которая не конвертируется в число:

```js
console.log("test 3");
alert(isNaN("1s2ssa"));
```

Comment: 1) первый символ в названии не должна содержать цифру, разрешается буква, $ , _

Comment: @xes кхм, это Вы мне объясняете?

Comment: 2) если это исправить то js будет считать 1s2ssa переменной будет false

Comment: :)) Для себя пишу и ВАМ заодно правильно я понял или нет

Comment: 3) единственныыый способ узнать это 1s2ssa сделать строкой правильно ?

Comment: @xes Что узнать?

Comment: является в функции isNaN эти данные 1s2ssa ТNaN или нет

Comment: @xes Этого кроме Вас никто не знает. Потому что Ваша строчка кода вырвана из контекста. В ответе Вам что-то непонятно?

Comment: контекста нет я сам придумал пример т.к. с функция NaN ничего не выводила, теперь понятно почему не выводила из-за 1 и 2 пункта, можео сделать как 3 пункте строкой и получится, а можно еще как-нибудь вывести кроме преобразования к строке ?

Comment: @xes Я не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите. У языка программирования есть некоторые правила, если писать код с нарушением этих правил, код работать не будет. Пример в вопросе написан с нарушением правил. Он не работает. Я объяснил, почему, и привел варианты работающего кода - два последних фрагмента. Что Вы хотите сделать "еще как-нибудь"?

Comment: да еще хочу узнать варианты как можно вывести, если конечно они есть

Comment: @xes Нет, вариантов больше нет ).

Comment: спасибо :))))))

Answer (score 0):

1s2ssa это не цифра, не строка - так как не в скобках, не функция - так как не объявлена, и тд.
Поэтому и парсер не понимает что вы ему говорите