# Система счисления?

Tags: javascript

функция parseInt превращает из 16 системы счисления в 10 систему счисления, а можно наоборот ?
Или нужно использовать toString ?

Comment: Вы ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908914

Comment: Igor  а я думал я поставил :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно говорить, что `parseInt` переводит строку, содержащую целое в определенной системе счисления, в число. У числа, самого по себе, нет системы счисления.

```js
var i = 31;
var a = i.toString(16);
// имейте в виду, что а - это строка
console.log(typeof a, a);
console.log(parseInt(a, 16));
```

Comment: как а может быть строкой если это переменная ?

Comment: @xes переменная, значение которой - строка

Comment: да toString переводит из 10 системы счисления в 16, parseInt из 16 в 10 систему счисления при этом если 16 число присвоить в переменную значение будет строка (как я это понял )

Comment: @xes, ты понял не правильно. `parseInt` - возвращает число, а `toString` - строку.

Comment: Grundy  получается тогда parseInt переводит из 16 в 10 систему счисления и возвращает число , а toString из 10 в 16 систему счисления и возвращает строку  правильно ?

Comment: @Grundy тогда убрать to получится string и мы ее переведем как строку правильно ?

Comment: @xes Вслушайтесь в эти слова: у числа нет системы счисления. Эта система есть у строкового представления числа.

Comment: @Igor строки это unicod где закодированы и цифры правильно ?

Comment: @xes При чем здесь Unicode? Зачем Вы используете слова, которых не понимаете?

Comment: @Igor parseInt и toString переводят число в строку и в зависимости от метода она преобразует в 16 или 10 это как с условными операторами if/else ?

Comment: @Igor ну unicod нам показывает строки а для внутреннего употребления он хранит в коде.Это как с числами для нас 10 система счисления, а для себя двоичная система счисления правильно ?

Comment: @xes Нет, неправильно, ничего общего с if/else. Вы знаете название языка и название функции. Не стоит ничего выдумывать. Надо просто про это прочитать.

Comment: @xes, посмотри, [что делает parseInt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633467/186999)

Comment: @Grundy Я знаю, что если число c буквами например 12b чтобы высчитать число нам надо использовать parseInt если число(дробное) например 12.5b используется parseFloat. parseInt и parseFloat в одном случае не преобразуют если начинаются с буквы например b12

Comment: @Grundy  у parseInt есть еще одна особенность она переводит и из 16 системы счисления в 10 систему счисления

Comment: @Grundy вообщем понятно, что я тупой :(((

Comment: @xes, если это **число**, тебе не надо использовать parseInt.

Comment: @Igor решил снова осмыслить этот момент и вот как я его понял parseInt вычисляет в строке число и если указать переводит в нужную систему счисления(2, 10, 16, 32), toString переводит число в строку в  нужную систему счисления(2, 10, 16, 32) верно ?

Comment: @xes да, верно.

Comment: @Igor ок, спасибо